# Does the Oracle PL/SQL optimizer optimize anonymous blocks or just stored program units?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've got lots of code inside anonymous blocks and I am worried that the PL/SQL optimizer doesn't optimize that code. Should I move my code from anonymous blocks into packages to make sure the optimizer does all the heavy lifting for me?

Comment: It is good to see you active in s.o. The question is overly broad, though your answer is quite detailed :). BTW, I really appreciate your contributions as a PLSQL "evangelist" for Oracle.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to your title question is: Yes. The optimizer optimizes anonymous blocks as well as stored program units. See script at end of answer to verify this statement.

The answer to your second question is: Yes, you should move your code out of anonymous blocks and into packages.

The reason for the second yes has nothing to do with performance, though. It has to do with the challenges of managing a large volume of code. It's much harder to manage code in blocks (script files) than in packages. Plus, when you store the code in a named program unit, you can take fuller advantage of all that Oracle Database does for you regarding code, including dependency management, program invalidation and automatic recompilation, code analysis with PL/Scope.

Now to see that the optimizer really does do its magic on anonymous blocks, consider the following sequence of statements, executed in 12.2.

First, I will set timing on and set the optimization level to the maximum possible (level 2 is the default and does the bulk of the optimizations; level 3 adds subprogram inlining and is recommended by the PL/SQL dev team).

```
SET TIMING ON

ALTER SESSION SET plsql_optimize_level = 3
/
```

In this first block, I use a cursor FOR loop to iterate through a whole bunch of rows. The optimizer *should* automatically compile this into the equivalent of a BULK COLLECT statement (fetching by default 100 rows at a time).

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     n   INT;
  3  BEGIN
  4     FOR rec IN (SELECT * FROM all_objects)
  5     LOOP
  6        n := n + 1;
  7     END LOOP;
  8  
  9     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (n);
 10  END;
 11  /

Elapsed: 00:00:01.943
```

So just under 2 seconds. Was it optimized? Let's check via a comparison.

In this second block, I no longer use a cursor FOR loop. Instead I declare a cursor explicitly and then iterate through the rows one at a time. By taking this approach, the optimizer can no longer safely convert this code to bulk fetching and so it is much slower.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     n   INT;
  3  
  4     CURSOR obj_cur
  5     IS
  6        SELECT * FROM all_objects;
  7  
  8     r obj_cur%ROWTYPE;
  9  BEGIN
 10     OPEN obj_cur;
 11  
 12     LOOP
 13        FETCH obj_cur INTO r;
 14        EXIT WHEN obj_cur%NOTFOUND;
 15        n := n + 1;
 16     END LOOP;
 17     
 18     CLOSE obj_cur;
 19  
 20     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (n);
 21  END;
 22  /

Elapsed: 00:00:04.648
```

Lots slower than the first block. Conclusion: anonymous blocks are optimized. And just to drive that point home, let's compare the first block's performance with that of a stored procedure:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE count_objects
  2  IS
  3     n   INT;
  4  BEGIN
  5     FOR rec IN (SELECT * FROM all_objects)
  6     LOOP
  7        n := n + 1;
  8     END LOOP;
  9  
 10     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (n);
 11  END;
 12  /

SQL> BEGIN
  2     count_objects;
  3  END;
  4  /

Elapsed: 00:00:01.875
```

Roughly the same. So there you have it: anonymous blocks are optimized just like stored program units. Enjoy!